# How to Embed Controllers in a Template using Symfony 4 directory structure

Tags: symfony, twig

I did a fresh Symfony installation by using Symfony Flex and the new skeleton belong to the next Symfony 4 directory structure. Next, I'm going to embed a controller from a twig template.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller(
        'App:Article:recentArticles',
        { 'max': 3 }
    )) }}
</div>
```

The same with *How to Forward Requests to another Controller*, I've tried:

```
 $response = $this->forward('App:Something:fancy', array(
    'name'  => $name,
    'color' => 'green',
));
```

But is not working.

There is way to do this?

Comment: Rendering embedded controllers is "heavier", if you must do it, you could define your controller as a service and call it by it's name..

Comment: You might consider this option too: `{{ render(app.request.baseUrl ~ '/article/recent', {"max": 3}) }}`

Answer (score 2):

When we using the short convention `a:b:c` to refer to the controller, it will only work if the controller belong to an installed bundle. For Symfony 4 structure your app source is not a bundle by default, so the above does not work.

For Symfony 4 approach you can refer to this controller using its fully-qualified class name and method:

```
App\Controller\ArticleController::recentArticlesAction
```

Embedding the controller into Twig templates:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\ArticleController::recentArticlesAction')) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I though so, but I hoped there was a shorter way.

Comment: @anacona16 You could perhaps try with some variables declared in `config/package/twig.yaml` until an evolution to accept `App:Controller:action`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
{# templates/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller(
        'App\\Controller\\ArticleController::recentArticles',
        { 'max': 3 }
    )) }}
</div>
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/embedding_controllers.html